# Flash - Paste frames into a position

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have 101 layers and I put in a movie clip which I didn't want to do. I copied all 101 layers and pasted them in another spot in Scene 1. I only problem is when I paste the layers in it postions everything in those layers to x-0 y-0, I want them to be in a position of x-350 y -550....how would I do that?

In side these layers are just shape as I was doing an handwriting effect on them.

Comment: Can you make flat available to download so I can see?

Comment: As Amy points out, use the Paste In Place option or Select All then Property Inspector to set properties for all. The only addition is, if those layers contain tweens, you should also use the Edit Multiple Frames option.

Comment: I think if he/she was literally doing "Paste Layers" or "Paste Frames," which is what would have to happen to be copying tweens & all, it would keep the original positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is Paste In Place. It's available from the edit menu, or I think the keyboard shortcut is Ctrl-Alt-Shift-V.

Another way to do it is to realize that everything you just pasted will still be selected, so use the properties panel to type in a new X and Y coordinate.